# Device to extend bluetooth range?

Tags: bluetooth

Is there device that will extend the range of Bluetooth? We currently have a Mac Mini setup to control a board room, but we have problems with a magic mouse when it is on the other side of the room from the mac mini.

Comment: I don't know if it's the best solution, but I solved this problem with a usb bluetooth dongle on the end of a long m/f cable that was under the center of the table (double sided tape). I had the parts on hand and it worked, so...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They're called "[Bluetooth Extenders](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=bluetooth+extender&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)." I have never used one so I can't offer specific advice, but I did look into them once for a similar problem.

Here's the one I planned on buying. Note that I never did so this is not a recommendation, just a suggestion: [http://www.amazon.com/Miccus-Home-RTX-Bluetooth-Transmitter/dp/B00713RSE0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00713RSE0)